# How to control mouse cursor using c?

Tags: c, opencv

As in windows there is a function setCursorPos in windows.h for controlling cursor position. What is the way to do this in ubuntu?

Comment: You probably would use the Xserver for that... check `expect` man page.

Comment: You actually mean moving mouse cursor by code? Either Xserver or even at lower lever, mouse interruptions might help but I got not idea so far.

Comment: see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675379/how-to-control-mouse-movement-in-linux). I think this is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use X11, this is the solution

```
Display *dpy;
Window root_window;

dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);
root_window = XRootWindow(dpy, 0);
XSelectInput(dpy, root_window, KeyReleaseMask);
XWarpPointer(dpy, None, root_window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);
XFlush(dpy); // Flushes the output buffer, therefore updates the cursor's position. Thanks to Achernar.
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433447/how-to-set-mouse-cursor-position-in-c-on-linux